# Xcode run button disappearing

Tags: ios, xcode, button

I have a problem with Xcode 7.1.1. The upper part of the UI (the container of the run button, manage scheme etc.) keeps disappearing when I close another opened project. If I have two project opened, closing one, the problem occcurs. I can't bring it back, the only option that I have is to close Xcode and open it again. Here's some screenshot of the page and the view menu.
The toolbar is visible, you can see it in the second and third screenshot, but its content it's hidden.
Anyone having the same problem or some solutions?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just click on CMD+R .It will appear

Comment: Pressing CMD+R the app starts in the simulator but the button doesn't re-appear.

Comment: It will appear it is hidden. double click on tool bar click on icon and text.

Comment: I have already tried that, see my last screenshot. The toolbar disappears but when it's showing again it's empty, clicking both Icon and Text or Icon Only.

Answer (score 10):

XCode will open the project with the interface configured the same way as the last file that was opened. If your interface is opening with the toolbar and project navigator minimized it means that you double clicked a file and opened it in its own window. XCode thinks that this was the last file opened so it uses this as the default.

To resolve right click on the top of the window and selecting "show toolbar" 
[image]

You can also hide same way by right clicking and hide toolbar.
[image]

Comment: I updated the question with a screenshot like yours. I see the toolbar but it's empty

Answer (score 4):

Keyboard shorcut: **cmd** + **alt** + **T**
Or in the menu: **View**>**Show Toolbar**

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and follow the guideline there to provide quality answer.

Answer (score 4):

For showing:

[image]

... and for hidding:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In XCode Preferences. You can set the behaviour of the toolbar. I suspect,it must be set to hide.[image]

Comment: It is set to the default show, like in your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

*i* used this way and worked for me

**View -> Show Toolbar**